# Hilbert Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

A positive integer $n$ is called a *Hilbert number* if $\exists a,b,d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ 4ab-a-b = d n$  and $d|a b$.

I ran an algorithm checking divisors for all $0\lt a,b\le500$, and the only numbers $n\le500$ for which I did not find a solution are

$\{1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,288,289,324,336,361,400,441,484\}$

Aside from $288,336$ they are all square numbers.  It might be that a wider check would exclude these numbers, as well as some (or all) of the squares, from the list.

My Question is : **Which numbers are not Hilbert Numbers ?**

Basic hunch tills me that square numbers are not **Hilbert Numbers**

Any idea how small it is, would help my a lot.

Thanks.

**Update** : does every prime number also Hilbert number ?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying the numbers on your list are *never* of the form $(4ab-a-b)/d$ where $d\mid ab$, or are you just saying that a finite search over all $a,b\le500$ failed to find them?

Comment: @BarryCipra the latter is true, i don't know if they are Hilbert numbers or not, i suspect that they are not

Comment: I've edited the question to improve its clarity.  If you don't approve, feel free to rollback.  (Note, I dropped $0$ from the list because your original version stipulated $n\gt0$.)

Comment: I managed to prove that if , for some integer $m$ , the number $n$ is $-d \mod 4m-1$ where $d|m$ then sure $n$ is Hilbert Number, first few of these are $-1 \mod 3$ and $-1,-2 \mod 7$ , $\cdots$ , but could not go any further.

Comment: Also proved for $4k+2$, $8k+5$,$12k+8$,$16k+15$ for $k \geq 0$ , the problem with my approach is that i look for patterns in modular arithmetic, which i highly doubt that it will answer my question(may be i am wrong).

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270061/hilbert-numbers